# python dictonary object not getting updated in memcache

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, web2py

I am working on a Web2py based web app which I am deploying on Google App Engine.
The problem which i am facing is. Everytime I update the memcache with a value as per below code my memcache gets flushed

```
 memclient = memcache.Client()
 temp_list = memclient.get('event_list')
 if temp_list is not None:
    temp_dict = client_list = memclient.get('event_list')
    logging.info('Before Updating')
    logging.info(temp_dict)
    temp_dict.update({str(form.vars.id):[str(form.vars.id),request.vars.first_name,request.vars.last_name]})
    logging.info('After Updating')
    logging.info(client_list)
    memclient.add('event_list', temp_dict)
    temp_dict= memclient.get('event_list')
    logging.info('After Updating in memcache')
    logging.info(temp_dict)
 else:
    temp_dict= {str(form.vars.id):[str(form.vars.id),request.vars.first_name,request.vars.last_name]}
    logging.info('Before Updating')
    logging.info(temp_dict)
    logging.info('After Updating')
    memclient.add('event_list', temp_dict)
    temp_dict= memclient.get('event_list')
    logging.info('After Updating in memcache')
    logging.info(temp_dict)
```

What should happen is if this code run twice both the old and new value should be part of dict object in memcache.
Although currently in logs I am checking the values are getting overridden in memcache with new values.

```
Logs output
First Run
Before Updating
{'658XXXXXXXXXXX84': ['658XXXXXXXXXXX84', 'roshan', 'jain']}
After Updating
After Updating in memcache
{'658XXXXXXXXXXX84': ['658XXXXXXXXXXX84', 'roshan', 'jain']}

Second RUN
Before Updating
{'658XXXXXXXXXXX84': ['658XXXXXXXXXXX84', 'roshan', 'jain']}
After Updating
{'658XXXXXXXXXXX84': ['658XXXXXXXXXXX84', 'roshan', 'jain'], '566XXXXXXXXX80': ['566XXXXXXXXX80', 'MS', 'Dhoni']}
After Updating in memcache
{'658XXXXXXXXXXX84': ['658XXXXXXXXXXX84', 'roshan', 'jain']}
```

The problem is that the new value is not getting updated.

Note: I am new to both Python and Web2py, although i have extensively used GAE for java, and I think Map> can be stored in cache.

THanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs aren't massively clear, but it looks like `add` only updates the cache if the key doesn't already exist. Since you've previously stored "event_list" in the cache, the second add call does nothing, and you just get the original value back on the subsequent get.

Instead you should use `memclient.set`.

Answer (score 0):

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36203962/440323), you should use `.set()` rather than `.add()`. Another option is to use web2py's `gae_memcache` module, which allows you to use the same API as you would use with web2py's standard `cache` mechanism:

```
from gluon.contrib.gae_memcache import MemcacheClient
cache.ram = cache.disk = MemcacheClient(request)
```

Then you can use `cache.ram` and/or `cache.disk` (both of which are just aliases for the memcache client) as described here: http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#cache